# How to replace only string end with number - preg_replace php

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Here is my string.

```
$text = 'I am  [pitch = "high"]Rudratosh Shastri[endpitch]. what is your name ? how  are you? sorry [pause ="3000"] i can not hear you ?[rate="-70.00%"] i still can\'t hear you[endrate] ? [rate="+50.00%"]why i can\'t hear you[endrate] ?';
```

I want to replace `[pause = "3000"]` by `<break time="3000ms">`

I have written following regex but it is selecting till the last `"]`

```
\[pause.*\"(\d+)\".*\"]
```

PHP : `$text = preg_replace("/\[pause.*\"(\w+)\".*\"]/", '<break time="$1ms"/>', $text);`

If I were to find a solution where the regular expression only selects 'any number'

```
any number"]
```

my problem would be solved.

But I am not able to find how to do it.

Do you have any suggestions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
\[pause[^]]*"(\d+)"]
```

Or (if there may be something else after the digits):

```
\[pause[^]]*"(\d+)"[^]]*]
                   ^^^^^
```

and replace with `<break time="$1ms"/>`. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wrFyvw/1)

**Details**

- `\[pause` - `[pause` substring
- `[^]]*` - 0+ chars other than `]`
- `"` - a double quotation mark
- `(\d+)` - Group 1: one or more digits
- `"]` - a `"]` substring.

[PHP demo](https://ideone.com/Fhmm5t):

```
$str = 'I am  [pitch = "high"]Rudratosh Shastri[endpitch]. what is your name ? how  are you? sorry [pause ="3000"] i can not hear you ?[rate="-70.00%"] i still can\'t hear you[endrate] ? [rate="+50.00%"]why i can\'t hear you[endrate] ?';
echo preg_replace('~\[pause[^]]*"(\d+)"]~', '<break time="$1ms"/>', $str);
// => I am  [pitch = "high"]Rudratosh Shastri[endpitch]. what is your name ? how  are you? sorry <break time="3000ms"/> i can not hear you ?[rate="-70.00%"] i still can't hear you[endrate] ? [rate="+50.00%"]why i can't hear you[endrate] ?
```

Comment: Thank you much  for your the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Your regex matches too much due to the last part `.*\"` If you remove that part you would have your match for the current example data, but the first `.*` still matches any character including for example characters like `"[]`.

What you could do is replace that first `.*` by matching the equals sign surrounded by horizonal whitespace character like `\h*=\h*`

Note that you don't have to escape the double quote.

You might use:

`\[pause\h*=\h*"(\d+)"]`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kljM6N/1)

That will match

- `\[pause` Match `[pause`
- `\h*` Match zero or more horizontal whitespace characters
- `=` Match =
- `\h*"` Match zero or more horizontal whitespace characters followed by a `"`
- `(\d+)` Capture in a group one or more digits
- `"]` Match `"]`

And replace with:

`<break time="$1ms">` or use `<break time="$1ms"/>`

For example:

```
$text = 'I am  [pitch = "high"]Rudratosh Shastri[endpitch]. what is your name ? how  are you? sorry [pause ="3000"] i can not hear you ?[rate="-70.00%"] i still can\'t hear you[endrate] ? [rate="+50.00%"]why i can\'t hear you[endrate] ?';
$text = preg_replace('/\[pause\h*=\h*"(\d+)"]/', '<break time="$1ms"/>', $text);
echo $text;
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/fQ0nW)